# Problem with Kernel of an linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Good afternoon, i have a problem with Kernel and image of linear Transformation, the exercise:

$T:\:R^{2}\rightarrow R^{2}$

$T\:(x,y)=(x,0)$

I make this:

$T\:(x,y)=(x,0)=(a,b)$

$\begin{cases}
x= & a\\
0= & b
\end{cases}$

Then

$Im_{f}=\left\{ (a,b)\::\:b=0\right\} $

and for the kernel

$T\:(x,y)=(x,0)=(0,0)$

$\begin{cases}
x= & 0\\
0= & 0
\end{cases}$

$Ker_{f}=\left\{ 0\right\} $

But the answer it's wrong, please help me, i cannot find the mistake

Comment: Do you know the definition of image and kernel of a linear transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is a small one. Note that $x$ is arbitrary, so $\text{ker}(f)=\{(x,y):x=0\}$. You solved for it correctly, but concluded incorrectly. $y$ is free to take any value, but $x$ must equal zero.

Comment: oh!, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: What (x,y) is mapped by $T$ to (0,0)?
To be more specific: Think about your $b$! Why should it be $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$  be the map that takes $(x,y)$ to $(x,0)$.  The image of $T$ is the set $$\{ T(x,y): (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\} = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}.$$
The kernel of $T$ is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ that are mapped to $0$ and so is equal to
$$\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: T(x,y) = (0,0)\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x,0)=(0,0)\} =  \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x = 0\} = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}.$$